# Spring boot and Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring boot with Mongodb and developing my new application. 
I can use MongoRepository for database operations as well as Mongotemplate.
I am using mongotemplate for my complex queries and MongoRepository small queries related to any field of POJO.

Is it ok to use both mongoRepository and MongoTemplate both in application ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use both.

Though note that Spring Data MongoDB (just like the other provider-specific flavors) has a [repository extension mechanism](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) to handle complex querying. Not to mention @Query. But if you want MongoTemplate you can do that too.

Comment: Probably good to mention that the repositories use the templates in their implementations.